# Batch file to monitor log file directory and send email alert when changes occur?

Tags: batch-file, logfile, file-monitoring

I am looking to create a batch file that one could place on a server and have it run via Task Scheduler on a daily basis to monitor the log file directory of an application. If there is a change in the name of a log file (error log appears for instance), the batch would send out an email to the administrator or administrator group.

What would be the general script for this type of batch?

Thank you.

Comment: A light batch script, but I have mainly been looking around for the most efficient scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a vbscript for this since it has the ability built in. Here is a general purpose script that you can modify to do what you want. Call it with cscript in Task Scheduler.

```
MonitorFolder()

Function MonitorFolder()
intInterval = "2"
strDrive = "C:" 
strFolder = "\\temp\\"
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:" & _ 
    "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2" )
strQuery =  _
    "Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent" _
    & " Within " & intInterval _
    & " Where Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile'" _
    & " And TargetInstance.Drive='" & strDrive & "'" _
    & " And TargetInstance.Path='" & strFolder & "'"
Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery (strQuery) 
WScript.Echo "Monitoring events...[Ctl-C] to end"
Do 

    Set objEvent = colEvents.NextEvent()
    Set objTargetInst = objEvent.TargetInstance

    Select Case objEvent.Path_.Class 
        Case "__InstanceCreationEvent" 
            WScript.Echo "Created: " & objTargetInst.Name
            SendEmail "FolderMonitor@Domain.com", "youremail@domain.com","Log File Created", "A new error log has appeared"
        Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent" 
            WScript.Echo "Deleted: " & objTargetInst.Name 
        Case "__InstanceModificationEvent" 
            WScript.Echo "Modified: " & objTargetInst.Name
    End Select 
Loop
End Function

Sub SendEmail(sFrom, sTo, sSubject, sMessageBody)
    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
    objMessage.Subject = sSubject 
    objMessage.From = sFrom 
    objMessage.To = sTo
    objMessage.TextBody = sMessageBody
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.myserver.com"
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
    objMessage.Send
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  that should give me a pretty good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a piece of code from my project to monitor log changes

It uses

- java nio for tracking log file changes
- sigar api(https://github.com/hyperic/sigar) for getting process id which will be used for stopping service
- java mail for sending mail in case of alert(method- sendMail)

dll or so file have to be added to build path to make use of sigar api

```
void initializePathAndWatcher(String directoryPath, String directoryName, Map<String, Object> data)
        throws IOException {
    yamlData = data;
    Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
    long pid = sigar.getPid();
    log.debug("Pid for current process: [" + pid + "]");
    path = Paths.get(directoryPath, directoryName);
    log.debug("Directory being watched: [" + path.toAbsolutePath() + "]");
    watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    path.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
    sigar.close();
}

void watcherServiceShutDown() throws IOException {
    watcher.close();
}

void trackEvent() throws Exception {
    try {
        while (true) {
            WatchKey watchKey;
            watchKey = watcher.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                Path fileName = ev.context();
                if (fileName.toString().equals(yamlData.get("directory.filename").toString())) {
                    log.debug(kind.name() + ": [" + fileName + "]");
                    StringBuilder absoluteFilePath = new StringBuilder(path.toString());
                    absoluteFilePath.append("/");
                    absoluteFilePath.append(fileName);
                    Path filePath = Paths.get(absoluteFilePath.toString());
                    long lineCount = Files.lines(filePath).count();
                    Boolean flagMatchFound = false;
                    if (statusFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("WARN")) {
                        flagMatchFound = Files.lines(filePath).skip(linePointer).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                                .anyMatch(s -> s.contains(yamlData.get("success.keyword").toString()));
                        if (flagMatchFound.equals(true)) {
                            log.warn("Bing server is back to normal");
                            statusFlag = "SUCCESS";
                            sendMail((String) yamlData.get("mail.success.subject"),
                                    (String) yamlData.get("mail.success.body"));
                        }
                    }
                    if (statusFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")) {
                        flagMatchFound = Files.lines(filePath).skip(linePointer).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                                .anyMatch(s -> s.contains(yamlData.get("error.keyword").toString()));
                        if (flagMatchFound.equals(true)) {
                            log.warn("Problem diagnosed on bing server");
                            statusFlag = "WARN";
                            sendMail((String) yamlData.get("mail.warn.subject"),
                                    (String) yamlData.get("mail.warn.body"));
                        }
                    }
                    linePointer = lineCount;
                    log.debug("Count of lines already processed active file: [" + linePointer + "]");
                }
            }
            watchKey.reset();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error occoured in trackEvent", e);
    }
    finally {
        watcher.close();
    }
}
```